# Create a runtime directory in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory, runtime, node.js-fs

I'm working on a service which handles file uploads to a server. In my service (Node.js) I want to create a certain file structure, put it in a directory, convert it to a blob and then upload it.

I am of course aware of the [Node file system (fs)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), but as far as I know it writes files/directories to disk. I have no interest in saving the directories, I just want to keep a directory in runtime to which I can add some files (also runtime) before converting it to a blob.

I also know about [fs.mkdtempSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsmkdtempsyncprefix-options), which you could use in [this way](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/create-temp-directory-app-node-js/). I don't want it to stay on disk however, in case something throws when trying to delete the temporary directory (see the `finally` block).

Do you know if there is any such functionality in Node.js? If not, is there any npm package which could help me achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the npm package called [memfs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memfs) and use it like this

```js
const { Volume } = require('memfs');
const fs = Volume.fromJSON({});

fs.mkdirSync('/mydir');
fs.writeFileSync('/mydir/myfile.txt', 'Hello world!');

// ... manipulate the in-memory file system as needed ...

// Convert the directory to a blob
const directoryBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(fs.toJSON())]);
```